# FORTNITE: Always a connection error on the first try

Tags: macos, networking, performance, fortnite-battle-royale

Whenever I play FORTNITE (Battle Royale), it fails to join a game *on the first try*.

On the second try, it succeeds.

I get to the load screen, and the progress bar doesn't move.

[image: FORTNITE load screen - progress bar stuck]

Finally, after a minute or two it times out and some variation of this error message is displayed:

[image: FORTNITE "We hit a roadblock" Connection error - Network Connection Lost]

I'm playing on a Mac, so it's *possible* Apple is doing something to screw with FN intentionally because of their current legal battle. (This is [why Save The World mode doesn't work](https://www.theverge.com/2020/9/18/21445092/fortnite-apple-save-the-world-macos-shutting-down-epic-games), for example.) But if this is caused by something else, and can be fixed by changing a setting (either in FN or in macOS, I would like to resolve this.

Finally, I'm not sure if this is related, but I keep on getting item screens offering me... nothing. I have the choice to either equip this nothing, or go to the next screen. Either way, I get nothing.

[image: FORTNITE Equip nothing]

If anyone experiencing similar issues knows of a resolution, please share.

Comment: I have the same issues and no solution. Maybe it is because of the Apple / Epic Games dispute?

Answer (score -1):

go in to creative make your and restart your game if your on ps4 restart and unplug your ps4 then plug it back in or wait till you'r gaming device comes up and it should work normally again.

Comment: "Go in to creative make your" ...your what?

Comment: ..furthermore, your answer would benefit from punctuation.